# Trying to update a dictionary with bigger dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to update a dicionary, for example:

```
dict1 = {"brand": "Ford","model": "Mustang","year": 1964}
```

Using this dictionary:

```
dic2 = {"brand": "Fiat","model": "Toro","color" : "Red","value": 20000}
```

The output must be:

```
dict1 = {"brand": "Fiat","model": "Toro","year": 1964}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you need to iterate over the dictionary you want to update and then replace the key's value (if present).

```
for i in dict1:
    try:
        dict1[i] = dic2[i]
    except:
        pass

dict1
{'brand': 'Fiat', 'model': 'Toro', 'year': 1964}
```

Update: as mentioned by: RoadRunner `try: .. except: ..` could be replaced by `if i in dic2`

```
for i in dict1:
    if i in dic2:
        dict1[i] = dic2[i]
```

Comment: Seems a little too much to have a `try..except` here just to update matching keys...

Comment: @RoadRunner True, I updated the solution. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2):

you can use a dictionary comprehension using `dict.get` method:

```
dict1 = {k : dic2.get(k, v)  for k, v in dict1.items()}
# {'brand': 'Fiat', 'model': 'Toro', 'year': 1964}
```

Comment: Even though this doesn't update `dict1` in-place, its still a good solution, as it doesn't pollute the original dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

An easy solution would be to just loop over the intersected keys and update `dict1`:

```
for key in dict1.keys() & dic2.keys():
    dict1[key] = dic2[key]

print(dict1)
# {'brand': 'Fiat', 'model': 'Toro', 'year': 1964}
```

or simply just check if the key exists before updating:

```
for key in dict1:
    if key in dic2:
        dict1[key] = dic2[key]

print(dict1)
# {'brand': 'Fiat', 'model': 'Toro', 'year': 1964}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution with [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
dict1 = {"brand": "Ford","model": "Mustang","year": 1964}
dict2 = {"brand": "Fiat","model": "Toro","color" : "Red","value": 20000}

dict3 = {k:dict2[k] if k in dict2 else dict1[k] for k in dict1}
```

Comment: But this creates a new dict vs updating dict1.